# Can PPK (NOT RTK) be done with any mapping drone?

Tags: gps, mapping, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, photogrammetry, base-station

If PPK is by definition post processed and does not require a live connection to the base-station, why wouldn’t be possible to use any drone and post process the resulting coordinate data (assuming software to do so and usage of a base-stations (or even CORS stations)

Comment: You can: https://wingtra.com/ppk-drones-vs-rtk-drones/ but the pros and cons of both methods are different.

Answer (score 3):

Post-processing depends on raw GNSS data being captured (pseudo-ranges for Code post-processing, Phase information for Carrier post-processing.) If the drone has only captured coordinates, you don't have the necessary information for post-processing.

Not all GNSS receivers will supply raw GNSS measurement data (for example, some u-Blox models will supply measurement data, others will not), and even if the GNSS receiver is able to supply the measurement data your drone software would have to store this in order for it to be available for post-processing.